# Where to install NeoEloquent

Tags: php, windows, laravel, neo4j

I am trying to setup Laravel 4 with Neo4J graph database for evaluating its viability for our main project. I am working on Windows 8.1 64-bit. Its my first time dealing with composer. I deployed Laravel and Neo4jPHP, and trying to do the same with NeoEloquent, with the following commands:

```
D:\composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
D:\laravel new Laravel
D:\Laravel\echo {"require":{"everyman/neo4jphp":"dev-master"}} > composer.json && composer install
D:\Laravel\echo {"require":{"vinelab/neoeloquent":"v1.0.5"}} > composer.json && composer install
```

The last command always results in giving out the error that Neo4jPHP is required;

```
- vinelab/neoeloquent v1.0.5 requires everyman/neo4jphp dev-master -> satisfiable by everyman/neo4jphp[dev-master].
- Removal request for everyman/neo4jphp == 9999999-dev
```

I have tried it many times now. Reinstalling everything for 4 times now. I even out of frustration ran it inside Neo4jPHP folder and it got installed there for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly. If you're using composer, then install Laravel through composer as well:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

Or if you havent got an alias for composer:

```
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel
```

Then run:

```
composer require vinelab/neoeloquent 1.0.5
```

Or

```
php composer.phar require vinelab/neoeloquent 1.0.5
```

Comment: D:\Laravel>composer require vinelab/neoeloquent 1.0.5
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Removal request for everyman/neo4jphp == 9999999-dev
    - vinelab/neoeloquent v1.0.5 requires everyman/neo4jphp dev-master -> satisf
iable by everyman/neo4jphp[dev-master].
    - Installation request for vinelab/neoeloquent 1.0.5 -> satisfiable by vinel
ab/neoeloquent[v1.0.5].

Comment: Go to your composer.json file and remove everyman/neo4jphp. Run "composer update" and try again..

Comment: @Stromgen only this is in the file: {"require":{"vinelab/neoeloquent":"*"}}

Comment: Did you run the first command from the root of your Laravel project? The composer.json file in your Laravel project will always have more depencies than that. At least the Laravel framework :)

Comment: If you're using composer, then install Laravel through composer as well. Use "composer create-project laravel/laravel"